# How to apply function of multiple matrices to each element of a list of matrices with python numpy?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, iteration

For sake of simplicity lets define the function to do only matrix multiplication:

```
f(matrix1, matrix2):
    #assume that matrix1.shape == np.transpose(matrix2).shape
    #both are 1 dimensional so this returns a scalar
    return matrix1 * matrix2
```

Now lets say I want to run this function a bunch of times for getting a sum:
- matrix1 - different each time
- matrix2 - same each time

I could write a for loop:

```
matrix_a1 = np.matrix([1,2])
matrix_a2 = np.matrix([3,4])
matrix_list = [matrix_a1, matix_a2]
matrixb = np.matrix([5,6],[7,8])
total = 0
for matrix in matrix_list
    total+= f(matrix, matrixb)
```

I want to write it like this:

```
sum(f(matrix_list, matrixb))
```

But this doesn't work because it tries to do matrix multiplication between matrix_list and matrixb instead of iterating over matrix_list.

How to I iterate over the matrix_list using numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert your list of matrices to a multidimensional array.

That will be easier if you step out of the comfort of the `matrix` object and go with plain arrays. Your first function, when given two arrays, can be rewritten with [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) as:

```
def f(array1, array2) :
    return np.dot(array1, array2)
```

You can now do:

```
>>> array_a1 = np.array([1, 2])
>>> array_a2 = np.array([3, 4])
>>> array_a = np.array([array_a1, array_a2])
>>> array_a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> array_b = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> array_b
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
>>> f(array_a, array_b)
array([[19, 22],
       [43, 50]])
>>> np.sum(f(array_a, array_b), axis=0)
array([62, 72])
```

You could even do :

```
>>> array_a1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> array_a2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> array_a = np.array([array_a1, array_a2])
>>> array_b = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])
>>> np.sum(f(array_a, array_b), axis=0)
array([[142, 156],
       [222, 244]])
```

Comment: @user2141019 If this answers your question, consider upvoting it, or even accepting it as an answer, using the arrow and check icons close to the header.